# rrdtool: illegal attempt to update

Tags: rrdtool

I'm attempting to read "historical" data from a text file and store in `rrdtool` to graph later.

I have created a new (empty) rrd database with

```
$ rrdtool create monitor_db.rrd --step 900 DS:col1:GAUGE:900:0:1000 DS:col2:GAUGE:3600:0:1000 RRA:MAX:0.5:1:1500
```

Then I attempt to update the database but I get an error

```
$ rrdtool update monitor_db.rrd --template col1:col2 1404249680:2:3
ERROR: monitor_db.rrd: illegal attempt to update using time 1404249680 when last update time is 1422146997 (minimum one second step)
```

The timestamp that `rrdtool` clains is the last update time, `1422146997`, is now and I'm trying to insert data from roughly half a year ago.

I understand that you have to insert data in chronological order to `rrdtool`, but the database should be empty since I have tried removing it and re-creating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rrdtool create has the `--start` option which does what you need without changing time for whole system. Defaults to 10 seconds ago.

Answer (score 1):

Before creating the database, I needed to change my system time.

1. Set system time so that it was earlier than the first timestamp in my dataset. In my case: `1404249680` (`2014-07-02T21:21` in ISO format).
2. Create the databse with `rrdtool create`.
3. Restore system time to normal.
4. Update the database with `rrdtool update`.

Editing the file attributes with `touch -d` wasn't enough, the starting date is probably stored somewhere in the database file.